# Gestting same youtube Channel id's when use youtube.search().list

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Im using Youtube api to get 10 random youtube channel id's and put them in a list, so i created a function to return this list :

```
def youtube_search():
    all_data = []
    search_response = youtube.search().list(
        part='snippet',
        maxResults=10,
        location=None,
        locationRadius=None,
        regionCode = 'TN',
        )
    response = search_response.execute() 
    for i in range(len(response['items'])):
  
       data = response['items'][i]['snippet']['channelId']

       all_data.append(data)
    
    return all_data
```

The problem is that it returns me the same id 10 times, exactly just 2 different id's ( 1 id 2 times and another one 8 times ) :

```
channel_data = youtube_search()
channel_data
['UC6UL29enLNe4mqwTfAyeNuw',
 'UC6UL29enLNe4mqwTfAyeNuw',
 'UCvR2R7j218tzejtTsb_X6Rw',
 'UCvR2R7j218tzejtTsb_X6Rw',
 'UCvR2R7j218tzejtTsb_X6Rw',
 'UCvR2R7j218tzejtTsb_X6Rw',
 'UCvR2R7j218tzejtTsb_X6Rw',
 'UCvR2R7j218tzejtTsb_X6Rw',
 'UCvR2R7j218tzejtTsb_X6Rw',
 'UCvR2R7j218tzejtTsb_X6Rw']
```

What is wrong ? why am i getting same id's and not all different?

Comment: it's working when i used type = "channel", but why i'm getting random channels and not in the specific region that i mentionned in the search.list endpint? ( regionCode='TN'), that means i wanted to get Tunisian channels in my example .

Comment: It could be that the `TN` region is not supported (quote from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#property-table)): *If a non-supported region is specified, YouTube might still select another region, rather than the default value, to handle the query.*

Answer (score 1):

For to obtain from the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint *only channel items*, there's the following request parameter:

> [**`type`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) (string)
>
> The `type` parameter restricts a search query to only retrieve a particular type of resource. The value is a comma-separated list of resource types. The default value is `video,channel,playlist`.
>
> Acceptable values are:
>
> - `channel`
> - `playlist`
> - `video`

Therefore, have your API call changed to:

```py
search_response = youtube.search().list(
    type='channel',
    part='snippet',
    maxResults=10,
    location=None,
    locationRadius=None,
    regionCode = 'TN',
)
```

and the `items` array you'll get back will contain only items referring to YouTube channels.

Comment: it's working , but do you have any idea why i'm getting random channels and not in the specific region that i mentionned in the search.list endpint? ( regionCode='TN'), that means i wanted to get Tunisian channels in my example .

Comment: It could be that the `TN` region is not supported (quote from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#property-table)): *If a non-supported region is specified, YouTube might still select another region, rather than the default value, to handle the query.*

Comment: You could also file a bug report directly to Google w.r.t this issue, through the company's [own issue tracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: I used another region Codes but it always get me the same list with the same id's, i think RegionCode parameter  is not even considered it, even when i removed it it shows me the same list.

Comment: I deem that behavior a bug of the API. Therefore, I'd recommend to file a bug report to Google. They have all the means to know why that's not working as specified by the official documentation of `Search.list`.